# vhdl arithmetic of parameters in embedded loops

Tags: arrays, for-loop, vhdl

Let's say, i have two types of arrays:

```
type A_type is array (0 to 39) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
type B_type is array (0 to 4) of std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
```

And corresponding signals:

```
signal A : A_type := (others => (others => '0'));
signal B : B_type := (  x"0706050403020100",
                        x"0f0e0d0c0b0a0908",
                        x"1716151413121110",
                        x"1f1e1d1c1b1a1918",
                        x"2726252423222120");
```

And now, somewhere in the process i want bytewise cast A to B using two for loops, one wrapping another (1):

```
process(clk)
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        for i in 1 to 5 loop
            for j in 1 to 8 loop
                A(i*j-1)  <= B(i-1)(7+8*(j-1) downto 8*(j-1));
            end loop;
        end loop;
    end if; 
end process;
```

Of course, i could make it in a more straightforward manner (2):

```
for i in 0 to 4 loop
    A(0+8*i) <= B(i)(7 downto 0);
    A(1+8*i) <= B(i)(15 downto 8);
    A(2+8*i) <= B(i)(23 downto 16);
    A(3+8*i) <= B(i)(31 downto 24);
    A(4+8*i) <= B(i)(39 downto 32);
    A(5+8*i) <= B(i)(47 downto 40);
    A(6+8*i) <= B(i)(55 downto 48);
    A(7+8*i) <= B(i)(63 downto 56);
end loop;
```

As a result, i want to have byte array A, that stores vector array B in such way: [proper_result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oCTM.png), and expression (2) gives it. But expression (1) gives this: [failed_result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgvZ1.png)
So the question is - am i missing something? Is it correct to multiply loop parameters (i*j), when acquiring array index?

p.s. i'm running xilinx vivado simulator with default sim options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't this:

```
A(i*j-1)  <= B(i-1)(7+8*(j-1) downto 8*(j-1));
```

be more like this:

```
A(8*(i-1)+j-1)  <= B(i-1)(7+8*(j-1) downto 8*(j-1));
```

Comment: @BrianDrummond I haven't simulated it (because it's not an MCVE so I can't be...). But Ive just checked it again visually and it looks OK to me. What do you think it should be? (I'd like to get it right.)

Comment: I just meant be careful of boundary conditions. It's odd to base both arrays off 0 and then base the loop counts off 1, and asking for unnecessary confusion. I'd fix that (using the array's attributes) then simplify the expression.